# Switching language while staying on the same page in PHP

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I'm struggling to find solution to my problem.
Basically, as the title says what I want to do is change language, but it redirects me to index.php as it is in the code below. The thing that there's on more if () {echo ...} statement complicates it even more. I've read some topics but i can't find the right answer. So here's my  header.php:

```
<?php
if ($lang == 'EN')
{
echo '
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="EN">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> iPhone 8 </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
 <header>
    <div id="navbar">
        <div id="container">
            <a href="index.php?lang='.$lang.'"><img src="Logos/mylogo1.svg" alt="logo" id="logo"></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="index.php?lang='.$lang.'"> Homepage </a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn"> iPhone 8 </a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="Review.php?lang='.$lang.'"> Review </a>
                    <a href="Specifications.php?lang='.$lang.'"> Specifications </a>
                </div>
            <li><a href="News.php?lang='.$lang.'"> News </a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn"> Media </a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="Photos.php?lang='.$lang.'"> Photos & GIFs</a>
                    <a href="Videos.php?lang='.$lang.'"> Audio & Video </a>
                </div>
            <li><a href="CompareiPhones.php?lang='.$lang.'"> Compare </a></li>
            <li><a href="Contact.php?lang='.$lang.'"> Contact </a></li>
            <li><a class="current" href="index.php?lang=EN"><img class="iconclass" src="Icons/ukicon.ico" alt="ENG"></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?lang=SK"><img class="iconclass" src="Icons/slovakicon.ico" alt="SK"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </header>';
}

else
{
$lang = 'SK';
echo '
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="SK">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> iPhone 8 </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
 <header>
    <div id="navbar">
        <div id="container">
            <a href="index.php"><img src="Logos/mylogo1.svg" alt="logo" id="logo"></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="index.php?lang='.$lang.'"> D.Stránka </a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn"> iPhone 8 </a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="Review.php?lang='.$lang.'"> Recenzia </a>
                    <a href="Specifications.php?lang='.$lang.'"> Špecifikácie </a>
                </div>
            <li><a href="News.php?lang='.$lang.'"> Novinky </a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn"> Média </a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="Photos.php?lang='.$lang.'"> Fotky & GIFy</a>
                    <a href="Videos.php?lang='.$lang.'"> Audio & Video </a>
                </div>
            <li><a href="CompareiPhones.php?lang='.$lang.'"> Porovnanie </a></li>
            <li><a href="Contact.php?lang='.$lang.'"> Kontakt </a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?lang=EN"><img class="iconclass" src="Icons/ukicon.ico" alt="ENG"></a></li>
            <li><a class="current"href="index.php?lang=SK"><img class="iconclass" src="Icons/slovakicon.ico" alt="SK"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </header>';

}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome Zsolti! This question might be closed soon as it is not 100% clear what are you asking. I removed the irrelevant tags from your question to help. I assume you are trying to make your PHP website available in 2 languages. [Internationalization and localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) is a very big and complex topic. One simple tip I could give you is to store the chosen language code in SESSION variable instead of passing it in GET query string.

Comment: There are a couple of other things I can suggest (that's a bit off-topic but it will help you). 1. Don't output large chunks of HTML using echo. End the PHP block `?>` and output the HTML instead. 2. Don't have two copies of your HTML for each language. Use only one and use some translation library to handle the translations on output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to maybe do is:

1) Have a function that will translate words based on current language *(there may also be a library/server-implementation to do this for you, but for limited words this method may work fine)*
2) Store the language in a session
3) As others have suggested, don't duplicate whole blocks of code

**/config.php**

```
<?php
# Set a root define for easy root access
define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);
# Set a root define folder for including functions
define('FUNCTIONS', ROOT_DIR.'/functions');
# Include our simple translator function (defined below)
include_once(FUNCTIONS.'/__.php');
# Include our language retrieval function
include_once(FUNCTIONS.'/getLang.php');
# Start session to store lang
session_start();
```

**/functions/__.php**

```
function __($text, $lang = false)
{
    # If lang is set, try to set from session
    if(empty($lang))
        $lang = (!empty($_SESSION['lang']))? $_SESSION['lang'] : 'EN'
    # Just return the text if the language is EN
    if($lang == 'EN')
        return $text;
    # Include our translator array
    if(!is_file($file = ROOT_DIR.'trans_'.$lang.'.php'))
        return $text;
    include($file);
    # See if there is a translation, if not just return the input
    return (isset($trans[$text]))? $trans[$text] : $text;
}
```

**/functions/getLang.php**

```
function getLang($default = 'EN')
{
    # Return the language if set, else send back default
    return (!empty($_SESSION['lang']))? $_SESSION['lang'] : $default;
}
```

**/trans_SK.php**

```
<?php
$trans = [
    'Homepage' => 'D.Stránka',
    'Review' => 'Recenzia',
    'Specifications' => 'Špecifikácie',
    'News' => 'Novinky',
    'Media' => 'Média',
    'Photos and GIFs' => 'Fotky & GIFy',
    'Compare' => 'Porovnanie',
    'Contact' => 'Kontakt'
];
```

header:

```
<?php
# Add config to top level pages
require_once(__DIR__.'/config.php');
# Set the language
if(!empty($_GET['lang']))
    $_SESSION['lang'] = strtoupper($_GET['lang']);

?><!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="<?php echo getLang() ?>">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> iPhone 8 </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
 <header>
    <div id="navbar">
        <div id="container">
            <a href="index.php"><img src="Logos/mylogo1.svg" alt="logo" id="logo"></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="index.php?lang=<?php echo getLang() ?>"><?php echo __('Homepage') ?></a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn"> iPhone 8 </a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="Review.php?lang=<?php echo getLang() ?>"> <?php echo __('Review') ?> </a>
                    <a href="Specifications.php?lang=<?php echo getLang() ?>"> <?php echo __('Specification') ?> </a>
                </div>
            <li><a href="News.php?lang=<?php echo getLang() ?>"> <?php echo __('News') ?> </a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn"> <?php echo __('Media') ?> </a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="Photos.php?lang=<?php echo getLang() ?>"> <?php echo __('Photos and GIFs') ?></a>
                    <a href="Videos.php?lang=<?php echo getLang() ?>"> Audio & Video </a>
                </div>
            <li><a href="CompareiPhones.php?lang=<?php echo getLang() ?>"> <?php echo __('Compare') ?> </a></li>
            <li><a href="Contact.php?lang=<?php echo getLang() ?>"> <?php echo __('Contact') ?> </a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?lang=EN"><img class="iconclass" src="Icons/ukicon.ico" alt="ENG"></a></li>
            <li><a class="current"href="index.php?lang=SK"><img class="iconclass" src="Icons/slovakicon.ico" alt="SK"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </header>
```